# How to git bzr push after git commit --amend?

Tags: git, bazaar

After doing a `git commit --amend` one has to `git push --force`[1] in order to get the desired history (i.e. have `base <- corrected commit` instead of `base <- wrong commit <- corrected commit <- merge of the former` which is necessary to `git push` without `--force`).

How to do that with `git-bzr`? `git bzr push` doesn't have a `--force` option or an equivalent.

---

[1] after clarifying to not destroy changes of other contributors, i.e. that one is using a private/non-visible remote branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git bzr push` has an `--overwrite` option which seems to be missing in the usage message which has been displayed to me, but is in the output of `git bzr push -h`. It seems to do what `git push --force` does.